# Why I can't send messages in a @tasks.loop in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I have a problem: I can't send message in a @tasks.loop() function.

When I try to get the channel object with `self.client.get_channel(channlid)`, it return me a Nonetype variable.

My code :

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord.ext import tasks
from datetime import date, datetime

channlid = 934533675083792465
global channel
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Blagues(client))

class Blagues(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.index = 0
        self.blaguedujour.start()
    
    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def blaguedujour(self):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(channlid)
        channel.send("a")


    
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("test")
```

my error:

```py
PS C:\Users\baron_btjit4i> & C:/Users/baron_btjit4i/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/baron_btjit4i/Desktop/Autrebot/main.py
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'blaguedujour'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 168, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\baron_btjit4i\Desktop\Autrebot\Cogs\blagues.py", line 20, in blaguedujour
    channel.send("a")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You're calling `client.get_channel` before the client is ready. So, the client cannot find the channel you're looking for, and `channel` becomes `None`.

This happens because you are starting `blaguedujour` in the initialization of your `Blagues` class.

## Solution

### Explanation

Instead of starting the task in `__init__`, you should start in when the client is ready, in `on_ready`. This can be accomplished by adding a [`commands.Cog.listener()`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#nextcord.ext.commands.Cog.listener) in your `Blagues` cog.

### Code

```
class Blagues(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.index = 0
    
    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def blaguedujour(self):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(channlid)
        channel.send("a")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready():
        self.blaguedujour.start()

    
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("test")
```

### Aside

`channel.send()` is a coroutine: it must be awaited. Use `await channel.send("a")` instead.